# Why has a heap has been corrupted?

Tags: c++, opencv

When I run this code I get `A heap has been corrupted`

Here is my code:

```
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;

//This program with take a Video, separate it into it's blue, green and red channels and display them. 
//It will then convert the video into HSV and do the same with it's hue, saturation, and value channels
int main() {
    Mat src, hsv, hls;
    Mat blue, green, red, hue1, saturation1, value, hue2, light, saturation2;
    bool quit = false;
    VideoCapture videoCapture(0);
    //create window
    cv::namedWindow("SplitImage");
    while (!quit) {
        //read in image
        videoCapture >> src;
        //convert image to hsv and hsl
        cvtColor(src, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
        cvtColor(src, hls, CV_BGR2HLS);

        //copy src to blue, green, and red matrices
        src.copyTo(blue);
        src.copyTo(green);
        src.copyTo(red);

        //copy hsv to hue1, saturation1, and value matrices
        hsv.copyTo(hue1);
        hsv.copyTo(saturation1);
        hsv.copyTo(value);

        //copy hls to hue2, light and saturation2
        hls.copyTo(hue2);
        hls.copyTo(light);
        hls.copyTo(saturation2);

        //resize windows
        Size size = Size(200, 200);
        resize(src, src, size);
        resize(hsv, hsv, size);
        resize(hls, hls, size);
        resize(blue, blue, size);
        resize(green, green, size);
        resize(red, red, size);
        resize(hue1, hue1, size);
        resize(saturation1, saturation1, size);
        resize(value, value, size);
        resize(hue2, hue2, size);
        resize(light, light, size);
        resize(saturation2, saturation2, size);

        //get number of rows, columns, and channnels
        int nRows = size.height;
        int channels = src.channels();
        int nCols = size.width * channels;

        //put matrices in array
        Mat matrices[9] = { blue, green, red, hue1, saturation1, value, hue2, light, saturation2 };
        //declare the pointers that will access the matrices' data
        uchar * p[9];
        //for readability I will access the pointer with
        //these constants instead of numbers
        const int blueIdx = 0, greenIdx = 1, redIdx = 2,
            hue1Idx = 3, sat1Idx = 4, valueIdx = 5,
            hue2Idx = 6, lightIdx = 7, sat2Idx = 8;
        //make blue matrix blue, green matrix green and red matrix red
        //and make hue matrix only have hue, saturation matrix only have saturation, and value matrix only have value
        for (int row = 0; row < nRows; row++) {
            //each element in p points to the first element in the row of each matrix
            //for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            //  p[i] = matrices[i].ptr<uchar>(row);
            //}
            for (int col = 0; col < nCols; col += channels) {
                //std::cout <<"separating at pixel coordinate"<< "(" << col << ", " << row<<")" << std::endl;
                // remember that pointer + 0 is the blue pixel, pointer + 1 is the green
                // pixel and pointer + 2 is the red pixel
                //turn pixel in blue matrix blue
                /*p[blueIdx][col + 1] = 0;
                p[blueIdx][col + 2] = 0;*/
                blue.data[row*nCols + col*channels + 1] = 0;
                blue.data[row*nCols + col*channels + 2] = 0;
                //turn pixel in green matric green
                //p[greenIdx][col + 0] = 0;
                //p[greenIdx][col + 2] = 0;
                green.data[row*nCols + col*channels + 0] = 0;
                green.data[row*nCols + col*channels + 2] = 0;
                //turn pixel in red matrix red
                //p[redIdx][col + 0] = 0;
                //p[redIdx][col + 1] = 0;
                red.data[row*nCols + col*channels + 0] = 0;
                red.data[row*nCols + col*channels + 1] = 0;

                // remember that pointer + 0 is the hue pixel, pointer + 1 is the saturation
                // pixel and pointer + 2 is the value pixel
                //turn pixel in hue matrix hue
                /*p[hue1Idx][col + 1] = 0;
                p[hue1Idx][col + 2] = 0;*/
                hue1.data[row*nCols + col*channels + 1] = 0;
                hue1.data[row*nCols + col*channels + 2] = 0;
                //turn pixel in saturation matric saturation
                /*p[sat1Idx][col + 0] = 0;
                p[sat1Idx][col + 2] = 0;*/
                saturation1.data[row*nCols + col*channels + 0] = 0;
                saturation1.data[row*nCols + col*channels + 2] = 0;
                //turn pixel in value matrix value
                /*p[valueIdx][col + 0] = 0;
                p[valueIdx][col + 1] = 0;*/
                value.data[row*nCols + col*channels + 0] = 0;
                value.data[row*nCols + col*channels + 1] = 0;

                //turn pixel in hue matrix hue
                /*p[hue2Idx][col + 1] = 0;
                p[hue2Idx][col + 2] = 0;*/
                hue2.data[row*nCols + col*channels + 1] = 0;
                hue2.data[row*nCols + col*channels + 2] = 0;
                //turn pixel in saturation matric saturation
                /*p[lightIdx][col + 0] = 0;
                p[lightIdx][col + 2] = 0;*/
                light.data[row*nCols + col*channels + 0] = 0;
                light.data[row*nCols + col*channels + 2] = 0;
                //turn pixel in light matrix value
                /*p[sat2Idx][col + 0] = 0;
                p[sat2Idx][col + 1] = 0;*/
                saturation2.data[row*nCols + col*channels + 0] = 0;
                saturation2.data[row*nCols + col*channels + 1] = 0;


            }
        }

        //put indentifying text on each matrix
        Point textPosition = Point(5, 10);
        putText(src, "src", textPosition, FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);//THIS IS LINE 131 WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
        putText(hsv, "hsv", textPosition, FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);
        putText(hls, "hls", textPosition, FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);
        putText(blue, "blue", textPosition, FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);
        putText(green, "green", textPosition, FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);
        putText(red, "red", textPosition, FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);
        putText(hue1, "hue1", textPosition, FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);
        putText(saturation1, "saturation", textPosition, FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);
        putText(value, "value", textPosition, FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);
        putText(hue2, "hue", textPosition, FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);
        putText(light, "light", textPosition, FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);
        putText(saturation2, "saturation", textPosition, FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);

        //concatenate images
        Mat topRow, middleRow, bottomRow, finalImage;
        std::vector<Mat> top = { src, blue, green, red };
        std::vector<Mat> middle = { hsv, hue1, saturation1, value };
        std::vector<Mat> bottom = { hls, hue2, light, saturation2 };
        hconcat(top, topRow);
        hconcat(middle, middleRow);
        hconcat(bottom, bottomRow);
        std::vector<Mat> allRows = { topRow, middleRow, bottomRow };
        vconcat(allRows, finalImage);

        //show matrices in window
        cv::imshow("SplitVideo", finalImage);

        if(cv::waitKey(30) == 'q') quit = true;
    }
}
```

The code takes in video from the webcam a shows the red green and blue channels, it then converts it to HSV and shows the hue saturation and value channels, it then convert the video to HLS and shows the hue light and saturation channels. Theses are displayed side by side in one window

As you can see in the code, I have commented out another method of doing the same thing by using `<Mat object>.ptr<uchar>(row)` to get a pointer to each row instead of using `<Mat object>.data` to get a pointer to all of the data. When I use the commented out method the code runs without errors. I could just use that, but I want to know why the `<Mat object>.data` method isn't working.

I'm confident that the `<Mat object>.data` lines are what is causing the error even though the error does not occur on those lines because I've gotten the same error in another application that also uses the same `<Mat object>.data` code and I get the same error. (what I've posted is the simpler of the two applications)

Comment: The number of array operations like `blue.data[row*nCols + col*channels + 1] = 0` is a prime opportunity to write past the end of an array.  Your code has a pile of them.   This example ASSUMES `row*nCols + col*channels + 1` is less than the number of elements in the array (since array indexing is zero based) and will access past the end of the array otherwise.

Comment: According to AddressSanitizer you have heap-buffer-overflow  at least  in this line:

    `blue.data[row * nCols + col * channels + 1] = 0;` , and this mistake will be repeated in the next similar lines.

Comment: That's a pretty poor (and error prone) implementation, especially the for loop zeroing out 18 matrices element by element. Couple of [`split`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#split)s and [`merge`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#merge)s along with a single mat of zeros ought to do the job in way that's a lot easier to follow. Perhaps even [`mixChannels`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mixchannels) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not multiply col*channels. You are already advancing it by a number of channels in the loop. So you should write e.g.

```
blue.data[row*nCols + col + 1] = 0;
```

etc